# Should I read R.I.P.D. "City of the Damned" comic before or after watching the movie? the original comic?

Tags: suggested-order, r.i.p.d

R.I.P.D. "City of the Damned" comic is a prequel to R.I.P.D. movie. But it was published later.

In which order should I read/watch R.I.P.D. things?

Published? (original comic, movie, "City of the Damned")?

Chronological? ("City of the Damned", original comic, movie; or "City of the Damned", movie, original comic)?

Main comic first, then movie related chronologically? (original comic, "City of the Damned", movie).

Please explain why you recommend a specific order.

P.S. I'm aware that the original comic and the movie [differ a lot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40012/how-is-the-movie-adaptation-of-r-i-p-d-different-from-the-comic). But not sure where the prequel stands - I'm assuming it's closer to the movie than the original comic?

Comment: May I suggest "instead of"?

Answer (score 2):

City of the Damned was written specifically as an intro to the movie. If you read the rest before you would have an idea of the story (but not really).

I would save the other four for after the movie. Less "adaptation-loss" issues; you could almost treat it as another completely different tale.